# Rails "The parameter passed to #in? must respond to #include?"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, error-handling, include, actioncontroller

as a follow up of another question here, i have added the following code to my records_controller.rb

```
if params[:order].in? %s[year artist title]
  # adds ORDER to the scope
  @records.merge!( Record.order("? DESC", params[:order]) )
end
```

but then i got an error:

```
"The parameter passed to #in? must respond to #include?"
```

what does this mean? What do i need to change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/Object/in%3F):

> **in?(another_object) public**
>
> Returns true if this object is included in the argument.
>
> Argument must be **any object** which responds to **#include?**

`include?` responds to an array of object which should be in format `%w[year artist title]` but not to a **symbol** as you have written `%s[year artist title]`

```
%w[year artist title] # => ["year", "artist", "title"] can be used for include? and in?
%i[year artist title] # => [:year, :artist, :title] can be used for include? and in?

%s[year artist title] # => :"year artist title" which is a symbol that can not be used for include? or in?
```

Answer (score 0):

```
%s[year artist title]
=> :"year artist title"
```

It's a symbol, guess you like to check if param is one of the strings. Try to use `%w` instead.

```
if params[:order].in? %w[year artist title]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Another situation:**

You'll receive this same error if your array is `nil`

I had the same problem but was because I was not handling the `nil` for my array:

```rb
my_string.in? my_array
```

if `my_array = nil` I got: `(The parameter passed to #in? must respond to #include?)`

To fix this I just changed:

```rb
my_string.in? my_array || []
```

Now if `my_array = nil` I got false